# Delay CSS3 transitions

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I created a CSS3 menu item, i want to display the `articles` item in a special way : If you click on the 4th items it should display the first one, then the second one, then the third with a small delay between them, like 0.5s.

In the same way, ifyou click onthe 2nd it should popup the first one and the second one after a small delay.

It's supposed to nice & smooth :)

Well, now it's still not what i want to achieve( here a live version of what i got http://jsfiddle.net/vH4DV/4/)

Do you think i can do this with CSS3 only ? Should i use Jquery ?

Thanks for your help !

### EDIT

Finally get this done, here is the final live version http://jsfiddle.net/vH4DV/21/

Comment: I think you can only do this via JavaScript...but I would love to learn a CSS solution if one exists

Comment: @stackErr Can you explain more how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/vH4DV/19/

Instead of:

```
   .ac-container input:checked ~ article{  
    height: 140px;
    -webkit-transition: all linear .25s;
    -moz-transition: all linear .25s;
    -o-transition: all linear .25s;
    -ms-transition: all linear .25s;
    transition: all linear .25s;
    opacity:1;
    }
```

Be more specific for your transitions.

```
.ac-container input:checked ~ .how{
    height: 140px;
    -webkit-transition: all linear .25s;
    -moz-transition: all linear .25s;
    -o-transition: all linear .25s;
    -ms-transition: all linear .25s;
    transition: all linear .25s;
    transition-delay: .3s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
    opacity:1;
}

.ac-container input:checked ~ .About{
    height: 140px;
    -webkit-transition: all linear .25s;
    -moz-transition: all linear .25s;
    -o-transition: all linear .25s;
    -ms-transition: all linear .25s;
    transition: all linear .25s;
    opacity:1;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ .references{
    height: 140px;
    -webkit-transition: all linear .25s;
    -moz-transition: all linear .25s;
    -o-transition: all linear .25s;
    -ms-transition: all linear .25s;
    transition: all linear .25s;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay: .6s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .6s;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ .contact{
    height: 140px;
    -webkit-transition: all linear .25s;
    -moz-transition: all linear .25s;
    -o-transition: all linear .25s;
    -ms-transition: all linear .25s;
    transition: all linear .25s;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay: .9s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: .9s;
}
```

Comment: Nice ! But why the 'About us' section isn't droping down?

Comment: Forgot to add that class. Updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: Oh i do not forget, i just trying to fix some stuff: the width of the "article" are not ok, and the menu works backwards. The first button shows 4 articles it should drop down only one, the 2nd button should shows 3 articles etc...